# Fast way to "improve" the length of a unit length vector

Tags: c++, c, optimization, precision, intrinsics

Paying for a full vector normalization in performance-critical code when it is known that the vector is already almost unit-length seems wasteful.

Does anyone know of a fast, practical method to bring the length of a double-precision 3D vector closer to 1? I'm imagining an iterative method based on Newton-Raphson iterations or limited Taylor expansion around 1.

[Here](https://github.com/dictoon/appleseed/blob/master/src/appleseed/renderer/modeling/bsdf/specularbtdf.cpp#L143-L150) is an actual real-world situation where such a routine could be useful. The `incoming` vector is already almost unit length, but without an explicit normalization it still triggers assertions down the line.

Using SSE 2, SSE 4.2 or AVX intrinsics is OK.

Comment: I'm not so sure a little square root is so costly. But anyway, around x=1 the graph of x^2 has derivative 2, i.e it's like a line that's rises 2 units per one unit forward in x direction. So you can estimate x in this region (from the square of Euclidian distance) by subtracting 1, dividing by 2, and adding 1. I haven't checked how that would work out performance wise, and only you can know whether your "already almost" is close enough.

Comment: Try and benchmark, then ask for details. SO is not a discussion forum.

Comment: Note that what @Cheersandhth.-Alf suggests turns out to be the first-order Taylor expansion of the square root function near `x`, though apparently reached by a different route.  You can improve it by adding more terms (the next is -((x-1)^2)/8, but I anticipate that you will soon pass the point where the `sqrt()` function is more efficient.  Note, too, that you can use the Taylor series error bound term to determine whether these approximations will be close enough for you.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Thanks, I didn't think of it that way. But now that you mention it, as I recall MacLaurin series is reached by considering derivatives, and Taylor series by considering MacLaurin with offset? It's so long ago I remember almost nothing, except how baffled I was in the classroom when a lecturer proceeded to derive a Taylor series, in some exchange with a student. And I wondered how the heck he could do that, how awesome that was. Now, I think that he probably had that memorized for the occasion... :)

Comment: I should have said the expansion of `sqrt(x)` near **1**, of course.  "Near x" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: "without an explicit normalization it still triggers assertions": does it really matter that the norm isn't exactly one ? It shouldn't. Can you pinpoint an expression where it makes a difference ? It could be the case that the best cure is to simply remove the assertion (or test against, say 1.001).

Comment: @YvesDaoust It's just that the code expects a certain (but arbitrary) level of accuracy. All I needed was a very cheap operation that could bring the normalization accuracy to that level. The solution outlined below works like a charm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem at hand boils down to finding (an approximate) [reciprocal square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Iterative_methods_for_reciprocal_square_roots).

SSE and AVX include an approximate reciprocal square root machine instruction, `rsqrt`, that is particularly well suited for this. Per the original [AMD64 Architecture Programmer's Manual, volume 1](http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/24592_APM_v11.pdf), the maximum relative error of the reciprocal square root variants is at most 1.5×2<sup>-12</sup>, or less than 0.0004.

If you use GCC, you can use the [`__builtin_ia32_rsqrtss()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Built-in-Functions.html#x86-Built-in-Functions) SSE built-in function to compute the reciprocal square root of the squared length of the vector, and multiply the vector components by the result, to get an "almost unit" vector.

Note that both SSE and AVX provide functions that speed up the calculation of the squared length, as well as multiplying each component. (You'll need to copy the scale factor to a vector of equal size, though.)

---

Without SSE/AVX, the general problem is that we wish to multiply the vector components by f(*S*) ≃ sqrt(1/*S*) == 1/sqrt(*S*), where *S* is the inner product (dot product) of the vector and itself, i.e. its length squared; but sqrt() is considered too slow, and *S* is known to already be close to 1.

Any function f(*S*) whose value is between 1 and sqrt(1/*S*), within the range we consider "close to 1", will work. The simplest I can think of are functions of form f(*S*) = (*C* + 1 - *S*) / *C*. For *S* = 0.5<sup>2</sup> to 2<sup>2</sup> (i.e. for vectors with length between 1/2 and 2), *C* is 6.

If we did not have any hardware support for reciprocal square root, the first approximation I would try would be along the following lines:

1. Compute the squared length *S* of the vector
2. Compute *M* = 0.125 * (9 - *S*)

   Note that any constant pair *C*<sub>1</sub> and *C*<sub>2</sub> = 1 + 1 / *C*<sub>1</sub> should work, only the range and rate of convergence varies. I picked *C*<sub>1</sub> = 1/8 for this example simply because it is exact in IEEE-754 floating-point representation, and typically multiplication is much faster than division. Other values (like 1/6 I mentioned above for range 0.5 to 2) are inexact and may need finessing by hand (adjusting the least significant unit one way or another in the two constants).
3. Multiply each component of the vector by *M*.

If that did not yield good enough results, I'd stop worrying about it, and use (hardware) square root instead. (On some architectures, casting the squared length to single precision for computing the scale factor can yield a significant speedup. Not on x86/AMD64, however.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, much appreciated. I actually get pretty good results with a simple Newton-Raphson iteration: M = (3 - S) * 0.5. This seems to converge much faster than M = (9 - S) * 0.125.

Comment: One thing that often makes people think sqrt is slow is that they are not using `-fno-math-errno` with gcc (or whatever the equivalent on other compilers is) so the compiler generates a costly call to a libc function that tests for degenerate cases, instead of directly using the hardware instruction.

Comment: @MarcGlisse It's not that `sqrt` is slow; just that it's slower than, say, a couple additions and a multiplication. The software I linked to in my post computes hundred billions square roots in the course of one run. Every small bits of optimization help. Adjusting the length of a nearly unit-length 3D double-precision vector using one Newton-Raphson iteration appears to be about 2.7 times faster than a plain normalization.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: Fully agreed. Also, GCC still does not vectorize operations too well, so if you can normalize vectors in groups of two, four, eight, or sixteen (depending on precision and whether using AVX256 or earlier), you can often do that in roughly the same time you can normalize one. (If you use GCC's vector intrinsics.) Applies to `rsqrt`, too. Newer GCC versions are supposed to be able to vectorize `sqrt(v)` with `v` being any vector type, without relying on arch-specific built-ins, but I haven't checked the results recently.

Comment: (Darned markup..) @FrançoisBeaune: Yes. Like I mentioned, different values of *C* have different regions of convergence; (0 < *S* < *C*) in this case, with smaller regions converging faster. You could get even faster convergence with *C* = 3/2, but remember that it will only work for *S* < *C*. The best *C* here is the smallest one that covers the entire range. (And that means the length of the unnormalized vector must be less than sqrt(*C*).)

Comment: @NominalAnimal Got it. Just to clarify, the vectors I wish to "adjust" have a length that usually deviates from unity by less than 10^-5.

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune All I am saying is to do things one step at a time. First make sure the exact square root computation is done efficiently, and only then try replacing with less precise versions. That also makes the benchmarks more meaningful.

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune: "Usually" does not cut it; it's the worst case you need to worry about, and handle correctly.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: I work with high-performance computing (classical molecular dynamics), and my approach is similar. First, make sure it works, and the results are correct. Then, see how the entire computation can be sped up. In some cases that is through approximations, but nowadays cache locality and memory throughput is much more important (affect execution time in wall-clock units the most). I also worry about network latencies, and have gotten familiar with the issues in mitigating latencies via planning the steps the work is done.

Comment: In this particular case, I do believe grouping the vectors to be normalized so that several (2,4,8,16) can be normalized at the same time, would yield most speed benefits. Then, alternate versions of the normalization function (chosen at compile time) can be written, taking advantage of the SSE/AVX extensions available. Or even generic GCC vectorization. These are then easy to microbenchmark against each other, especially via `__builtin_ia32_rdtsc()` (and pinning the process to a specific core to avoid TSC variances between cores on certain CPUs).

Comment: @MarcGlisse The code works and the results are correct. We are performance-conscious and go to great lengths to make the code as fast as possible by using state-of-the-art algorithms, finely tuned compiler flags, cache-friendly access patterns, vectorization/parallelization where applicable, and by profiling profusely with VTune. Regarding the length of the input vectors: It obviously depends on the exact calculations, but the vectors deviate from unity only because of accumulated numerical error. We can assume that they are within a factor 10^-5 from unity.

Comment: That close to 1 I do believe *M* = (3 - *S*)/2 is the best approximation. It reduces relative error of 1e-5 (10⁻⁵) down to about -1.5e-10, and it does have the interesting property of ensuring the length of the vector (after multiplying all components by *M*) is less than one (if the original length of the vector is between 1-1e-5 and 1+1e-5).